# Guardar el resultado de una consulta en una variable C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Quiero obtener el ID de la `DB SQL Server` usando `C#`, lo que esta entre **--**
es donde me da el error me dice que no se puede convertir de `int` a `string`, y lo que quiero es obtener el ID que seria un `INT`..

```
string query = "select max(ID)-1 from DOLAR";
conexion.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
bool converted = Int32.TryParse(**command.ExecuteNonQuery()**, out int id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id );
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (!converted) { MessageBox.Show("La cadena de entrada no tiene el valor correcto"); }
```

Pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cambia ExecuteNonQuery por ExecuteScalar.

Comment: gracias por constestar, si lo cambio me da el mismo error solo que este dice " no se puede convertir de 'Object' a 'String'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que usar el `ExecuteScalar()` para obtener el valor de esa query

```
conexion.Open();

string query = "select ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) AS LASTID from DOLAR";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

int lastId = Convert.ToIn32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Ahora bien

- Usa el `ISNULL()` en caso de no heber registros, asi puede devolver un valor por defecto
- Solo obtiene el valor, despues si necesitas restar a esteo o sumar realizalo en la variable, no en la query

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono